# Memory management of static consts in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, memory-management, unsafe-unretained

I was watching the [F8-2016 Building iOS Tooling at Facebook Scale](https://developers.facebook.com/videos/f8-2016/building-ios-tooling-at-facebook-scale/) video, when I've noticed an interesting code part at 7:01.

Facebook defined a static constant in Objective-C this way:

`static __unsafe_unretained NSString * const kAuthorKey = @"AUTHOR";`

Up to now, I declared my static constants the same way, but without the `__unsafe_unretained`. Without this modifier, the constant will be `strong`, but since it exists always during the application run, it doesn't matter if it is `strong` or `__unsafe_unretained`.

Am I missing something? Do Facebook has any reason to use `__unsafe_unretained`?

Comment: The only think I can think of is that Facebook was trying to support a platform where `__weak` didn't exist (iOS 4 and below).  Or because `const` specifies that this pointer is constant pointer to a heap address where the memory will never change, and it's safe to use `__unsafe_unretained`

Comment: Or maybe Facebook is working in a non-arc environment.

Comment: Constant strings are never deallocated anyways, so it doesn't matter much.